# Up-cycling iMac Pro RAM

Tags: memory, imac

I have a bunch of iMac Pro RAM sticks (remnants of an upgrade) and I'm thinking of using them in other computers.
What are my options? I tried looking for an answer but never got a definitive one.
Are those strictly "server" RAMs or they can be used in gaming systems or something?

These are 8 Sticks of 8GB DDR4 2666MHz RDIMM.

Comment: It's ECC, so it probably won't work in a 'regular' i7 type machine. ECC is usually for Xeons. [idk for absolute certain, so not an answer.]

Comment: Yes; Xeon processors, more specific Xeon compatible motherboards, support ECC memory.  DDR4 is DDR4 only Apple has written firmware to prevent any DDR4 module.

Comment: @Ramhound - The latter part of your comment is a little confusing; could you clarify? Thanks :)

Comment: RDIMM sound like registered DIMM. That is not the same as ECC, but your motherboard and [on die] memory controller will need to support it. Doing a quick search (any motherboard, filter DDR4, filter RDIMM) on tweakers yields 112 hits, including on modern gaming board. https://tweakers.net/moederborden/vergelijken/#filter:q1YqKMpMTvXNzFOyMtBRKi5ITXbLzClJLSpWsqpWMrcwBlFliTlKVtFKhmYGJkqxtTpKJubG5kjiJpZGQOHaWgA

Comment: @Tetsujin - Apple goes to considerable effort to prevent third-party components from working on their devices.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have many 3rd party components in many Macs here. Your assertion seems to have some kind of agenda & appears to have no relevance as to whether a computer can or cannot run ECC RAM. Servers run ECC, domestic computers run non-ECC because it's cheaper. High end Mac Pros have always been built like servers, running multiple Xeons rather than domestic single CPU machines running i7s etc. The iMac Pro runs [LRDIMM ECC RAM](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DID2627DP128/) on 8 to 18-core Xeon CPUs. Some Dell servers run similar architecture (but are more expensive ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - I was being a little sarcastic about Apple's aftermarket component support.